# Slow network performance in Docker container

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine, docker-network

I'm running the latest docker/ docker-machine on OSX Yosemite and VirtualBox and I'm trying to connect to a lein ring server running in a container from the host the loading is slow as in like Load time is over 1 min The following is my configuration

Docker 1.12.0
Docker Machine 0.8.0
VirtualBox 5.0.24

My Docker Machine

> "ConfigVersion": 3, "Driver": { "IPAddress": "192.168.99.100",
>   "MachineName": "default", "SSHUser": "docker", "SSHPort": 49478,
>   "SSHKeyPath":
>   "/Volumes/NASMAC/VMs/.docker/machine/machines/default/id_rsa",
>   "StorePath": "/Volumes/NASMAC/VMs/.docker/machine", "SwarmMaster":
>   false, "SwarmHost": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3376", "SwarmDiscovery": "",
>   "VBoxManager": {}, "HostInterfaces": {}, "CPU": 1, "Memory": 1024,
>   "DiskSize": 20000, "NatNicType": "82540EM", "Boot2DockerURL": "",
>   "Boot2DockerImportVM": "", "HostDNSResolver": false, "HostOnlyCIDR":
>   "192.168.99.1/24", "HostOnlyNicType": "82540EM",
>   "HostOnlyPromiscMode": "deny", "UIType": "headless", "NoShare": false,
>   "DNSProxy": true, "NoVTXCheck": false }, "DriverName": "virtualbox",
>   "HostOptions": { "Driver": "", "Memory": 0, "Disk": 0,
>   "EngineOptions": { "ArbitraryFlags": [], "Dns": null, "GraphDir": "",
>   "Env": [], "Ipv6": false, "InsecureRegistry": [], "Labels": [],
>   "LogLevel": "", "StorageDriver": "", "SelinuxEnabled": false,
>   "TlsVerify": true, "RegistryMirror": [], "InstallURL":
>   "https://get.docker.com" }, "SwarmOptions": { "IsSwarm": false,
>   "Address": "", "Discovery": "", "Agent": false, "Master": false,
>   "Host": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3376", "Image": "swarm:latest", "Strategy":
>   "spread", "Heartbeat": 0, "Overcommit": 0, "ArbitraryFlags": [],
>   "ArbitraryJoinFlags": [], "Env": null, "IsExperimental": false },
>   "AuthOptions": { "CertDir":
>   "/Volumes/NASMAC/VMs/.docker/machine/certs", "CaCertPath":
>   "/Volumes/NASMAC/VMs/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem",
>   "CaPrivateKeyPath":
>   "/Volumes/NASMAC/VMs/.docker/machine/certs/ca-key.pem",
>   "CaCertRemotePath": "", "ServerCertPath":
>   "/Volumes/NASMAC/VMs/.docker/machine/machines/default/server.pem",
>   "ServerKeyPath":
>   "/Volumes/NASMAC/VMs/.docker/machine/machines/default/server-key.pem",
>   "ClientKeyPath": "/Volumes/NASMAC/VMs/.docker/machine/certs/key.pem",
>   "ServerCertRemotePath": "", "ServerKeyRemotePath": "",
>   "ClientCertPath":
>   "/Volumes/NASMAC/VMs/.docker/machine/certs/cert.pem",
>   "ServerCertSANs": [], "StorePath":
>   "/Volumes/NASMAC/VMs/.docker/machine/machines/default" } }, "Name":
>   "default" }

My docker Image

> { "Id":
>   "819132073e36a026222ad0da90899a0daf1e735ce0f8623202740b355556c136",
>   "Created": "2016-08-28T23:35:03.957961657Z", "Path": "/bin/bash",
>   "Args": [ "lein", "with-profile", "dev", "do", "start-dev" ], "State":
>   { "Status": "running", "Running": true, "Paused": false, "Restarting":
>   false, "OOMKilled": false, "Dead": false, "Pid": 3586, "ExitCode": 0,
>   "Error": "", "StartedAt": "2016-08-28T23:35:04.365339872Z",
>   "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z" }, "Image":
>   "sha256:618b57a0e5d07030a3f869607928f5e167b53a6f250f76f88325799888dcac94",
>   "ResolvConfPath":
>   "/var/lib/docker/containers/819132073e36a026222ad0da90899a0daf1e735ce0f8623202740b355556c136/resolv.conf",
>   "HostnamePath":
>   "/var/lib/docker/containers/819132073e36a026222ad0da90899a0daf1e735ce0f8623202740b355556c136/hostname",
>   "HostsPath":
>   "/var/lib/docker/containers/819132073e36a026222ad0da90899a0daf1e735ce0f8623202740b355556c136/hosts",
>   "LogPath":
>   "/var/lib/docker/containers/819132073e36a026222ad0da90899a0daf1e735ce0f8623202740b355556c136/819132073e36a026222ad0da90899a0daf1e735ce0f8623202740b355556c136-json.log",
>   "Name": "/lonely_ritchie", "RestartCount": 0, "Driver": "aufs",
>   "MountLabel": "", "ProcessLabel": "", "AppArmorProfile": "",
>   "ExecIDs": null, "HostConfig": { "Binds": [
>   "/Users/kendallarneaud/Documents/Git/ngc-race-along.docker:/data" ],
>   "ContainerIDFile": "", "LogConfig": { "Type": "json-file", "Config":
>   {} }, "NetworkMode": "default", "PortBindings": { "3000/tcp": [ {
>   "HostIp": "", "HostPort": "" } ], "9000/tcp": [ { "HostIp": "",
>   "HostPort": "" } ] }, "RestartPolicy": { "Name": "no",
>   "MaximumRetryCount": 0 }, "AutoRemove": false, "VolumeDriver": "",
>   "VolumesFrom": null, "CapAdd": null, "CapDrop": null, "Dns": [],
>   "DnsOptions": [], "DnsSearch": [], "ExtraHosts": null, "GroupAdd":
>   null, "IpcMode": "", "Cgroup": "", "Links": null, "OomScoreAdj": 0,
>   "PidMode": "", "Privileged": false, "PublishAllPorts": true,
>   "ReadonlyRootfs": false, "SecurityOpt": null, "UTSMode": "",
>   "UsernsMode": "", "ShmSize": 67108864, "Runtime": "runc",
>   "ConsoleSize": [ 0, 0 ], "Isolation": "", "CpuShares": 0, "Memory": 0,
>   "CgroupParent": "", "BlkioWeight": 0, "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
>   "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null, "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
>   "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null, "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
>   "CpuPeriod": 0, "CpuQuota": 0, "CpusetCpus": "", "CpusetMems": "",
>   "Devices": [], "DiskQuota": 0, "KernelMemory": 0, "MemoryReservation":
>   0, "MemorySwap": 0, "MemorySwappiness": -1, "OomKillDisable": false,
>   "PidsLimit": 0, "Ulimits": null, "CpuCount": 0, "CpuPercent": 0,
>   "IOMaximumIOps": 0, "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0 }, "GraphDriver": {
>   "Name": "aufs", "Data": null }, "Mounts": [ { "Source":
>   "/Users/kendallarneaud/Documents/Git/ngc-race-along.docker",
>   "Destination": "/data", "Mode": "", "RW": true, "Propagation":
>   "rprivate" } ], "Config": { "Hostname": "819132073e36", "Domainname":
>   "", "User": "", "AttachStdin": true, "AttachStdout": true,
>   "AttachStderr": true, "ExposedPorts": { "3000/tcp": {}, "9000/tcp": {}
>   }, "Tty": true, "OpenStdin": true, "StdinOnce": true, "Env": [
>   "no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16",
>   "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
>   "HOME=/root", "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle",
>   "LEIN_ROOT=true", "LANG=C.UTF-8", "PYTHON_VERSION=2.7.9" ], "Cmd": [
>   "/bin/bash", "lein", "with-profile", "dev", "do", "start-dev" ],
>   "Image": "rand/docker-clojurescript:latest", "Volumes": null,
>   "WorkingDir": "/data", "Entrypoint": null, "OnBuild": null, "Labels":
>   {} }, "NetworkSettings": { "Bridge": "", "SandboxID":
>   "8b5479b9b22a6d653509c99f9b291593ca7664339666cf40bee55044f3c1d778",
>   "HairpinMode": false, "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
>   "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0, "Ports": { "3000/tcp": [ { "HostIp":
>   "0.0.0.0", "HostPort": "32773" } ], "9000/tcp": [ { "HostIp":
>   "0.0.0.0", "HostPort": "32772" } ] }, "SandboxKey":
>   "/var/run/docker/netns/8b5479b9b22a", "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
>   "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null, "EndpointID":
>   "d4164a411f5ca1992eb724c4cd5cb2f013a1eb909b6d3e5f395d07df84ff34f2",
>   "Gateway": "172.17.0.1", "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
>   "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0, "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2", "IPPrefixLen":
>   16, "IPv6Gateway": "", "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02", "Networks":
>   { "bridge": { "IPAMConfig": null, "Links": null, "Aliases": null,
>   "NetworkID":
>   "fb82d366a9a2ad010bda7cdf4e6cb33f083a678756cfdfed01f90d3d2c317dfa",
>   "EndpointID":
>   "d4164a411f5ca1992eb724c4cd5cb2f013a1eb909b6d3e5f395d07df84ff34f2",
>   "Gateway": "172.17.0.1", "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2", "IPPrefixLen": 16,
>   "IPv6Gateway": "", "GlobalIPv6Address": "", "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
>   "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02" } } } }

I'm not sure what other information I am to submit to debug this situation. Is there that can be done to improve performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To speed this up you can also use http://docker-sync.io - it has been specifically build for this case under OSX.

Comment: do i run this in conjunction with the docker image?

Comment: Yes, you do. You can also use `docker-sync-stack start` to run both, your compose stack and your sync stack. Otherwise you run `docker-sync start` to run the sync stack and then `docker-compose up` to run your stack

Answer (score 1):

Mounting of home (mac) folders in VirtualBox is known to be extremely slow with data transfer. Try using Docker for Mac instead, or copy your content to a named volume. e.g.:

```
docker create volume --name myvol
docker run --rm --name data-container -v myvol:/data alpine top
docker cp dir/with/files data-container:/data
docker rm -f data-container
```

This gives you a volume `myvol` which you can mount on any container. The volume data is kept in the VirtualBox host.

Comment: @Akaline I am using docker for mac! So you are saying that instead of hosting the files on the OSX host. Copy it to the docker-machine and mount the volume from the docker-machine to the container? I'm new to docker so not sure how this works in terms of editing...can you explain by e.g.?

Comment: I gave two different solutions. Docker4mac is great for development but it's not meant for production. For production, you'll end up having to copy files to either the foreign host or to a docker volume (the code I listed). Start by using docker4mac to get to speed with docker. It'll be faster than VirtualBox.